# I cant init bootstrap-year-calendar

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello**

I trying init bootstrap-year-calendar , i have no idea why its not working.

In this case i downloaded files but i was trying with npm with same effect.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-year-calendar.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  <div data-provide="calendar"></div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>

<script>

      $('#calendar').calendar();

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js not function fadeIn.
try use

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function after the dom content load finish. So try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#calendar').calendar();
});
```

Comment: I think your bootstrap-year-calendar.js is not loading. I changed thta code it is working. Edited part: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-year-calendar/1.1.1/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>

Comment: Oh, great, but now i have next issue. https://ibb.co/TMxzg28 Some idea ?